# How to manage delay in loading from kafka topic into table using table api in pyflink

Tags: python, join, apache-flink, pyflink, flink-table-api

i am loading data from two kafka topics into tables using table api in pyflink and going to do join operation what will happen if the data from one of the kafka topics loaded into the corresponding table with a delay? if delay happens , how can i manage?

so we have tried windows and it is not working properly so the problem arises is we have to first find the delay happpen while loading data from kafka topic to table and then if the delay happen then how can we manage that delay in table api pyflink.

how to find the delay and manage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Currently we are working on loading data from Kafka topic into tables ,actually we have two tables and loading data from two different Kafka topic. source1 and source2 and joining these two table and writing into another Kafka but we don't know how to handle the delay between two records stream coming at different event time. and also we dont know how to use timestamps and watermarks so can you please clarify this with an example or code....